# How can I get the structure of $form->getData()

Tags: forms, symfony

I have difficulties to get the structure of the array / object form->getData(). also I wanted to know there is a way to get it easily.

I have tried the following but there are to many information therefore it isn't readable

```
$data = $form->getData();
$for_twig_data = var_dump($data);
```

I also tried the following, but $data_value_value is an object, therefore I cannot fetch throught it:

```
  $liste_key = '';
  foreach($data as $data_key => $data_value)
  {
      $liste_key = $liste_key."[".$data_key."]";
      if(is_array($data[$data_key]))
      {
        foreach($data_value as $data_value_key => $data_value_value)
        {
          $liste_key = $liste_key."(".$data_value_key.")".$data_value_value;
          if(is_array($data[$data_key][$data_value_key]))  
          {
            foreach($data_value_value as $data_value_value_key => $data_value_value_value)
            {
              $liste_key = $liste_key."{".$data_value_value_key."}";
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  getData just returns the data used to create the form.  Are you trying to get the actual data objects for use within a twig template?

Comment: I want the data submited by the user. The data retrieve after: $form->handleRequest($request) and if($form->isValid())

Comment: Ok.  But you already know what the structure is because you built it to pass onto the form.

Comment: right, I know it looks like that: $data['articles'][1]['author'] but not so easy to figure out. Anyway I would like to check if it looks as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you have another possibility than iterating through the dataset, but I would advice you to write a recursive function to do that so you don't have to nest the for-loops and elements can have infinite child layers.

Something like this should work:

```
$liste_key = '';
$this->parseFormData($liste_key, $data);
...

function parseFormData(&$liste_key, $data){
    foreach($data as $data_key => $data_value)
    {
        $liste_key = $liste_key."[".$data_key."]";
        if(is_array($data[$data_key]))
        {
            $this->parseFormData($liste_key, $data_value)
        }
    }
}
```

(I have not tested the function so I can not garantee the syntax is correct, but the approach should be right)

...

For an output dump do this:

```
function yourformAction() {
   if ($form->isValid()) {
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($form->getData());
       $liste_key = '';
       $this->parseFormData($liste_key, $form->getData());
       print_r($liste_key); // you could also use echo $liste_key;
       die; // this is optional and will stop further processing
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works but only to a certain deep inside the $data. I mean my object look like this $data['articles'][1]['author'] but to reach author I have to do it $data_bis = $data['articles'][1]; $author = $data_bis->getAuthor(). It behave like any array until I reach this deep...

Comment: Add a dump of $form->getData() and another one with the result you are getting from the function... then I will have a look at it tomorrow

Comment: you mean **var_dump($data_bis)** with $data_bis = $data['articles'][1]; ?

Comment: do echo '<pre>'; print_r($form->getData()); make a print_r($liste_key); after the parsing function (with echo '<pre>' you will get a formated output for arrays)

Comment: nothing to do with twig... just put the the echo and print statements into your controller function in the if clause when the form is valid

Comment: sorry I do not understand where in the function parseFormData() I should add the **echo** and the **print_r**

Comment: added an how to example

Comment: OK I got the data array in a better way. But the array is so long (I mean it has more than 10000 lines to be displayed.) it this normal? so many information in it like **[onDelete] => CASCADE** which is information from the object my form is based on. (Entity Articles). is it possible to get a summary?  **here is the beggining Array
(
    [articles] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Article Object
                (**
.... and then it goes in so much detail obout the article object

Comment: nope not possible since you are getting either theORM entity or the ORM entity parsed as an array structure